# Using Eloquent, how do I filter my Model-query to include only items that were created today?

Tags: date, model, laravel, eloquent

My app has a dashboard that must display the last 10 entries submitted today.

How do I filter my Eloquent query to show only items that were `created_at` today?

Edit: Is this the Eloquent way to do it?
`Entry::where('DATE(created_at)', '=', 'DATE()') [...]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why don't you use:

```
Entry::where('created_at', '>=', date('Y-m-d'))
```

if PHP is running on the same machine as the database server (so that the time is the same)?

Answer (score 1):

The time problem may come sometimes. PHP is running on the same machine as the database server then it will be safe.

Comment: It's a local PHP app. Same server, same time zone. (That should be in the previous answers' comments, by the way.)

Comment: I got the time problem in some applications on webserver. That is why I mentioned it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **Carbon Library** that comes with Laravel to do this easily.

```
Entry::where('created_at', '>=',Carbon::today())
```

Comment: How about for the current year with Carbon?