# Laravel ORM, date compare

Tags: php, laravel, orm

I'm using Laravel Framework.

I want  all of the rows for this day. This is what I tried:

```
DB::table('users')->where('created_at', '>=', date('Y-m-d H:i:s'))
```

(field `created_at` represented in database in format: `Y-m-d H:i:s`).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [my own question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14790027/using-eloquent-how-do-i-filter-my-model-query-to-include-only-items-that-were-c), where Eloquent is used, as well as Fluent.

Answer (score 49):

Hmmm...there was a good answer to this question which seems to have now disappeared.*

It was something like this:

```
User::where('created_at', '>=', new DateTime('today'))
```

Note: if you're putting this code in a file with a namespace, or might use a namespace in the future, you should prefix the DateTime class with a backslash: `new \DateTime('today')`.

*
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15052679/laravel-framework-how-to-get-today-queries

Comment: Beautifully put together.

Comment: This answer got my brain on the right track. `SomeModel::where('whatever', '=','0000-00-00')`

Comment: The given link is broken... any alternatives?

Answer (score 5):

`date('Y-m-d H:i:s')` returns date of now.

If you want results from start of the day you can replace it with `date('Y-m-d').' 00:00:00'`.

If you want results from last 24 hours you can replace it with `date('Y-m-d H:i:s',time()-86400)` (86400 = 24*60*60)

Answer (score 3):

For those who only need to compare a date without time, Lavarel provided a handy function *whereDate*:

```
User::whereDate('created_at', '>=', date('Y-m-d'));
```

http://laraveldaily.com/eloquent-date-filtering-wheredate-and-other-methods/

Answer (score 0):

I know that topic is old but may someone try to find a solution from search engines.

You can use:

```
User::whereDate('created_at', '=', Carbon::today()->toDateString());
```

You can visit this link if you want to know more about date comparison in Laravel using where.

[Eloquent date filtering: whereDate() and other methods](http://laraveldaily.com/eloquent-date-filtering-wheredate-and-other-methods/)

Answer (score 0):

Simply:

```
DB::table('users')->where('created_at', '>=', date('Y-m-d'). ' 00:00:00')
```

When getting all rows for this day(the time should be 00:00:00), so make sure to set the date condition to current date plus 00:00:00 i.e.

```
date('Y-m-d'). ' 00:00:00'
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score -1):

Use `whereDate`

```
$users = DB::table('users')
                ->whereDate('created_at', '2016-12-31')
                ->get();
```

other functions you may use are:  `whereDate / whereMonth / whereDay / whereYear / whereTime`