# Laravel 4 Eloquent Query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, eloquent

I am trying to query the 'created_at' field by the date for today:

```
$today = DATE('Y-m-d');
$logs = DB::table('bglogs')->where('DATE('created_at')','=',$today)->where('user_id','=',Auth::user()->id)->get();
```

It tells me that DATE('created_at') is an unknown column? Any suggestions, relatively new to Eloquent so I am sure I've missed something obvious.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: 6/10/2014

Wanted to note that I had to tweak it a bit as it was bringing back all records rather than a specific date. Not sure why. I finally got this working correctly. Thanks again to all who answered and I hope this update will help others in the future:

```
$logs = DB::select(DB::raw("SELECT * FROM bglogs WHERE DATE(created_at) = :today AND user_id = :user"), array('today'=>DATE('Y-m-d'), 'user'=>Auth::user()->id));
```

Comment: Try this

$today = DATE('Y-m-d');
$logs = DB::table('bglogs')->where('created_at','=',$today)->where('user_id','=',Auth::user()->id)->get(); The column created_at dont need to specify DATE function

Comment: possible duplicate of [Laravel ORM, date compare](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15053089/laravel-orm-date-compare)

Comment: That's what I thought to but it brings back no results from the DB and I've got records that should match that criteria.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try this ([Carbon](https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon) is available with `Laravel`):

```
$today = Carbon\Carbon::toDay()->toDateTimeString();
$logs = DB::table('bglogs')->where('created_at', $today)
                           ->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)
                           ->get();
```

Comment: Nice! Thanks for the heads up. I like that a lot better.

Comment: Also I assumed your `created_at` field was created using `timestamps()` method during migration.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use mysql functions you must use whereRaw and wite it in a single string.

In the other where, you can skip the second parameter if it will be equals (=).

```
$today = DATE('Y-m-d');
$logs = DB::table('bglogs')
    ->select(DB::raw('*'))
    ->whereRaw("DATE('created_at') = " . $today)
    ->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)
    ->get();
```

Hope its help you.

I recommend you dont declare alias if you will use the var just one time:

```
$logs = DB::table('bglogs')
    ->select(DB::raw('*'))
    ->whereRaw("DATE('created_at') = " . DATE('Y-m-d'))
    ->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)
    ->get();
```

Comment: This worked but I had to tweak it. Hope you can read this: $logs = DB::table('bglogs')
->select(DB::raw('*'))
->where(DB::raw("DATE('created_at')", '=', $today))
->where('user_id','=',Auth::user()->id)
->get(); Thank you again, really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

there is no need to use raw method when you can just define search criteria.
try this:

```
$today = DATE('Y-m-d');
$logs = DB::table('bglogs')
            ->where('created_at', '=>', $today.' 00:00:00')
            ->where('created_at', '<=', $today.' 23:59:59')
            ->where('user_id', '=', Auth::user()->id)
            ->get();
```

if problem still exists so check your table for existence of this created_at field.

Answer (score 0):

```
$today=date("Y-m-d");
$coustomers=Coustomer::where('created_at','like',"$today%")->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Carbon` class provided by laravel:

```
$today = Carbon::today();

$logs = DB::table('bglogs')
            ->where('created_at','>=',$today)
            ->where('user_id','=',Auth::user()->id)
            ->get();
```

**Or**

You can use php `date` functions to do this manually:

```
$today = new \DateTime(date('F jS Y h:i:s A', strtotime('today')));

$logs = DB::table('bglogs')
            ->where('created_at','>=',$today)
            ->where('user_id','=',Auth::user()->id)
            ->get();
```